# Text to Zip to base64 and vice versa, in Python

Tags: python, zip, base64, zlib

I have a 'text' that is converted to zip then converted to base64. How do I convert it back to plain text in python if I have that base64 value. ?

Comment: decode to binary, then unzip

Answer (score 2):

You convert the base 64 back, using [base64 module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/base64.html), and then the zip, using the [zipfile module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/zipfile.html).

Assuming `file.txt` was zipped into `file.zip`, and then the archive was converted to base 64 as `encoded.txt`:

```
import zipfile
import base64
base64.decode(open('encoded.txt'), open('file.zip', 'w'))
ZipFile('file.zip').extractall()
plaintext = open('file.txt').read()
```